# WP8 ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged delegate crashing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

bit of a noob when it comes to async operations but I am having some trouble with a ObservableCollection and not sure if the problem is because it is in an async method or not. When it tries to add the delegate it crashes with a System.AccessViolationException error... Here's the code:

```
public partial class ContactsList : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    static ObservableCollection<Contact> dataSource { get; set; }

    public ContactsList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        dataSource.CollectionChanged += this.dataSource_CollectionChanged;

        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(GetContacts(i.ToString()));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    private void dataSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<AlphaKeyGroup<Contact>> DataSource = AlphaKeyGroup<Contact>.CreateGroups(dataSource, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, (Contact s) => { return s.Name; }, true);
        ContactsLList.ItemsSource = DataSource;
    }


    public async Task GetContacts(string page)
    {
        try
        {
            string strCredidentials = Globals.APIKey;
            string strAuthorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strCredidentials));
            RestClient client = new RestClient(Globals.myURL);

            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/contacts.json?state=all&page=" + page);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + strAuthorization);
            request.Method = Method.GET;

            var rslt = client.ExecuteAsync(request, (r) =>
            {
                if (r.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Completed)
                {
                    if (r.Content == "" || r.Content == " ")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No Contacts Found");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataSource = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
                        var conts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ContactWrapper>>(r.Content);
                        foreach (ContactWrapper cont in conts)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                string name = cont.User.Name;
                                string email = cont.User.Email;
                                string mobile = cont.User.Mobile;
                                string phone = cont.User.Phone;
                                string jobtitle = cont.User.JobTitle;
                                dataSource.Add(new Contact("", "", "", "", "", email, "", jobtitle, mobile, name, phone, ""));
                            }
                            catch { }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch {}
      }
    }
 }
```

In the GetContacts method the dataSource collection gets added to, so the idea is that GetContacts is called 6 times and each time the return data is added to the dataSource.

When that happens I want to call dataSource_CollectionChanged to update the bound longlistselector on the XAMl page.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't want to update your LLS every time item is added (correct me if I misunderstood you) - delete subscription to event, and run updating method after await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

Comment: I tried that, but it actually doesn't wait, I have updated the GetContacts method to show what it does. I think as it is also running async it's not giving a final waitall... if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've build a [simple example basing on your code](http://1drv.ms/1eZkD7S) and it seems that your code is all right.

I think the problem may be in your Task `GetContacts(string page)` in `// Do stuff here` - check if you are not trying to change something within UI if so, do it by using Dispatcher:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
       { 
          //do UI stuff here; 
       });
```

*EDIT* - it turned out in the discussion that the Collection hadn't beed initialized on start.

Comment: What about MessageBox - is there a chance that it is invoked? Can you try to invoke it by Dispatcher?

Comment: No, I just commented it out and same result - it crashes on dataSource.CollectionChanged += this.dataSource_CollectionChanged; so it's before GetContacts is even called.

Comment: Do you have something other running (Task) or it the whole code? The situation is the same if you comment out everything in dataSource_CollectionChanged?

Comment: I just checked your example though and I wasn't initializing the collection at the start... it doesn't crash now :) thank you!

Comment: That is because you initialize your collection once again in Task `dataSource = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();` - delete that line. When you initialize new, you have it without event.

Comment: All fixed and all working!! Thank you, iv'e been banging my head on that one for 2 days :)